# jQuery: use var shortcut to assign data and how to chain function to run on load and click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a two-part question.

One: can I use the `last` variable I set to update the value on the line after `if (!last) {`? i.e., something like `last = size;`?

```
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    function updateCount() {
        var self = j$(this),
            last = self.data('last'),
            size = self.val().length,
            span = j$('.currentCount');

        if (!last) {
            self.data('last', size);
        } else if (last != size) {
            span.text(size);
            self.data('last', size);
        }
    }

    j$('textarea[id$=textBody]').on('propertychange change click keyup input paste', updateCount);
```

Secondly, can I chain my `.on('propertychange ...` line to have `updateCount` run as soon as the script is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

No, you can not use simply the assignment to the variable because there is no data-binding in jQuery. So updating `last` variable will never update the `data-last` of the jQuery object.

Question 2:

This is what I am used to do:

```
j$('textarea[id$=textBody]').on('propertychange change ...', updateCount).change();
```

Where `change()` automatically triggers the function.

Answer (score 1):

For Q1: No you can't. If you want data binding to work, you can try AngularJS where 2 way data binding between UI and model is possible.

Q2: My solution would be something like this using **immediate function**

```
 $('textarea[id$=textBody]').on('propertychange change click keyup input paste', (function(){
    updateCount();

    return updateCount;
    }()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `last` variable has a copy of the value in `self.data('last')`, it is not a pointer, so you would have to do something like this:

```
last = size;
self.data('last', last);
```

For the second question, you can trigger the event or just call the function:

```
j$('textarea[id$=textBody]').trigger('propertychange');
// or
j$('textarea[id$=textBody]').each(updateCount);
```